# How can I effectively achieve a multidimensional array in the Application scope?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic, multidimensional-array, vbscript

I'm looking to effectively setup what would most easily be done as a multidimensional array in the Application scope [for instance declared in the Global.asa file or Application("multi-array")] so that I can access it later. Single dimensional arrays work fine. Nested arrays, multidimensional arrays, collections in arrays, arrays in collections all seem to not work.

Comment: Some code would be helpful to know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

1 word, don't, application variables on IIS don't scale well with large access in classic ASP. I suggest you just use a standard server side include to include the data you wish without the overhead of an application variable.

Comment: While true and good advice, this is better suited as comment since you don't provide any real answer here.